# Equilateral Triangles On Sides of a Parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, transformation, symmetry

On the sides of a parallelogram $ABCD$, construct similarly oriented equilateral triangles $ABC_1, BCA_1, CDD_1$, and $DAB_1$. Let $N,P,Q$ and $M$ be the centers of the triangles, respectively. Show that the quadrilateral $MNPQ$ happens to be a parallelogram.

[image]

I think this is a really interesting problem. I found it in the *geometric transformations unit* in my textbook. The given hint is to use the (central) symmetry with center the intersection of the diagonals of the given parallelogram ($ABCD$). I am not sure I see it though. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is similar to Napoleon's Theorem.

Comment: Hint: whenever you have a quadrilateral $WXYZ$ such that opposite corners ($W,Y$ and $X,Z$) are symmetric through the same center $O$, it's a parallelogram.

Comment: Are you comfortable using vectors? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Think about what happens if you rotate the picture by 180° about the center of the parallelogram.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, may I ask you why is this true? Also how can we show that the points $Q,O,N$ and $M,O,P$ and collinear?

Comment: @CalvinLin, well, I know basic vector things and problems. I am not very good at using them, though.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, was my question clear, sorry?

Comment: There are a lot of answers solving the problem, please consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ R(X)$ be the $180^\circ$ rotation of the point $X$ about the center of parallelogram $ABCD$.

Show that

- $R(A) = C, R(B) = D.$
- $R(C_1) = D_1, R(A_1) = B_1$.   -> Note this isn't as symmetric as the rest because of the naming in the question. If we used cyclic notation like $ ABC_1, CDA_1$, then we would have $ R(C_1) = A_1$. In fact, $R(ABC_1) = R(CDA_1)$.
- $R(N) = Q, R(P) = M$.
- $NQ, PM$ bisect each other about the center,
- These points form a parallelogram.

Comment: Thank you for the response! May I ask you where the point $X$ is and what is the angle of rotation equal to?

Comment: @Katherine A) $X$ is the point that we're rotating, much like the function $f(x)$ is the function $f$ applied to $x$. B) It's 180 degrees (added in).

Comment: $R(C_1)$ can't be $A_1$, because $O$ is not the midpoint of $A_1C_1$?

Comment: @Katherine Ah, that's because I assumed that your naming was "cyclic", but it isn't (EG with $ABC_1$ I was expecting $CDA_1$. Let me fix.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't get it. For us to say that $R(C_1)=D_1$ we have to know two things: 1) $O\in C_1D_1$ and 2) $O$ bisects $C_1D_1$. How do we show this? Let me clarify that $O$ is the intersection of the diagonals of the given parallelogram $ABCD$

Comment: @Katherine There are more than 1 way to prove a statement. What other ways can you show it? For example, what can you say about $R(ABC_1)$?

Comment: I don't know. We can say for sure $R(A)=C,R(B)=D$, but we can't say anything for $R(C_1)$...

Comment: @Katherine Think about it, what condition in the question have you not used?

Comment: Well, maybe the fact that the triangles are equilateral and the points $M,N,P,Q$ are their centers, but I don't see how to use it to show to collinearity of $D_1,Q,O,N,C_1$ for example. This is needed for the solution of the problem as far as I understand the idea.

Comment: Can you help me, please?

Comment: @Katherine There are ways to prove that $R(C_1) = D_1$, that doesn't require us showing that $C_1 O D_1$ is a straight line (where $O$ is the center of rotation, which I intentionally didn't define). A) Can you show that $ R(ABC_1) = CDD_1$? If yes, this proves that $R(C_1) = D_1$. B) Next, consider the centers of these triangles. why does this give $R(N) = Q$?  C) Note that I have not shown that the points $ C_1, N, O, Q, D_1$ are a straight line (and in fact these 5 points need not be a straight line).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the above picture, we can use three pairs of congruent triangles to prove the conclusion.

1.For $\triangle MDQ$ $ and $ $\triangle PBN$,

$\alpha=\alpha'$, MD=BP,NB=DQ, $\triangle MDQ$ $\equiv$ $\triangle PBN$ (SAS), $\to$ MQ=NP (1)

2.For $\triangle MAN$ and  $\triangle PCQ$,

$\beta=\beta'$,MA=PC,AN=QC,$\triangle MAN$ $\equiv$ $\triangle PCQ$  (SAS), $\to$ MN=PQ (2)

3.For $\triangle MNP$ and  $\triangle MPQ$,
bb
MP=MP ,MQ=NP and MN=PQ  from (1)(2), $\triangle MNP$$\equiv$
$\triangle MPQ$ (SSS) $\to$

$\angle NMP=\angle QMP$, NP//MQ, with NP=MQ from (1),  MNPQ  is  a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

Yet an "other" proof.
The following picture...

[image: math stackexchange question 4068702]

introduces slightly different notations to have a simpler book keeping (and typing). Here, $O$ is the intersection of diagonals in the given parallelogram $ABCD$, the equilateral triangle constructed on $AB$ has the third vertex $X_{AB}$ and center $O_{AB}$, and similar notations apply to the other ones.

From the congruence (written as equality) $\Delta DAO_{DA}=\Delta BCO_{BC}$
of isosceles triangles
(case ASA on bases $AD=BC$) we get $AO_{DA}=CO_{BC}$. Together with $OA=OC$ we obtain
$$
\tag{$*$}
\Delta OAO_{DA}=\Delta OCO_{BC}\ ,
$$
since the angle between the pairs of corresponding sides also coincide.
Then $(*)$ implies

- $\widehat{ AOO_{DA}}=\widehat{ COO_{BC}}$, and from the colinearity of $A,O,C$ we obtain the colinearity of $O_{DA},O,O_{BC}$,
- $OO_{DA}=OO_{BC}$.

Similar properties can be extrapolated "from the violet pieces to the brown pieces" in the figure.

> So $O$ is the mid point of both segments
> $O_{DA}O_{BC}$ and $O_{AB}O_{CD}$, hence the quadrilateral
> $\color{blue}{O_{AB}O_{BC}O_{CD}O_{DA}}$ is a parallelogram.

(To obtain $O_{AB}O_{DA}=O_{BC}O_{CD}$ compare the two triangles with these segments as corresponding sides, and with the common vertex in $O$.)

$\square$

---

Note: The above is the long story for the proof using the reflection w.r.t. the center $O$ of $ABCD$. This reflection exchanges opposite sides of the parallelogram, thus also opposite constructed equilateral triangles, thus also their centers, and we land immediately at the above displayed property for
$\color{blue}{O_{AB}O_{BC}O_{CD}O_{DA}}$, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a proof via the complex geometry. Given the vertexes of the parallelogram at $z_1$, $z_2$, $-z_1$ and $-z_2$, the third vertexes of the equilateral triangles are

$$A = z_1e^{-i\frac\pi3} - z_2e^{i\frac\pi3}, \>\>\>
B = z_2e^{-i\frac\pi3} + z_1e^{i\frac\pi3}, \>\>\>
C = -z_1e^{-i\frac\pi3} + z_2e^{i\frac\pi3}, \>\>\>
D = -z_2e^{-i\frac\pi3} - z_1e^{i\frac\pi3}
$$

and their centers
$$X = \frac13(A+ z_1 -z_2) = \frac13 z_1(1+e^{-i\frac\pi3}) - \frac13z_2(1+e^{i\frac\pi3})$$
$$Y = \frac13(B+ z_2 +z_1) = \frac13 z_2(1+e^{-i\frac\pi3}) + \frac13z_1(1+e^{i\frac\pi3})$$
$$Z = \frac13(C- z_1 +z_2) = -\frac13 z_1(1+e^{-i\frac\pi3}) + \frac13z_2(1+e^{i\frac\pi3})$$
$$W = \frac13(D- z_2 -z_1) = -\frac13 z_2(1+e^{-i\frac\pi3}) - \frac13z_1(1+e^{i\frac\pi3})$$

Then, it is straightforward to verify

$$Y-X=Z-W,\>\>\>\>\>Z-Y = W-X$$

Thus, $XYZW$ is a parallelogram .